# How I can add a point in front of first element in linked list java?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, structure

I'm trying to write a function named addStart() to add new element in the front of first node in list Structures. please help me to figure it out.

I have 2 class named Waypoint and TourElement Class. Waypoint provides method to work with points. An Tour Element contains a lot of points.

//Waypoint.java

```
 public class Waypoint {
      int x  ;
      int y  ;
    public int getX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }
    public void setXY(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
```

//Tour Element.java

```
public class TourElement {
 private Waypoint points;
 private TourElement next;

  public void setWaypoint( Waypoint points)
 {
   this.points = points; 
 }
  public void setTourElement(TourElement next)
  {
      this.next = next;
  }
 Waypoint getWaypoint()
 {
     return this.points;
 }

 TourElement getNext()
 {
     return this.next;
 }
```

//I need help with addStart function
 //, which adds the way point in front of the first element. If the parameter is null the list is returned unchangend.

```
TourElement addStart(Waypoint wp) {
        if(this.next == null)
        {
            TourElement newTourElement = new TourElement();
            newTourElement.setWaypoint(wp);
            this.next = newTourElement; 
        }
        return this;
    }
```

//The addStart's test case:

```
public void test0AddStart() {
        TourElement elem = new TourElement();
        elem.setWaypoint(createWaypoint(2, 2));  

        elem = elem.addStart(createWaypoint(1, 1));
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {1, 1}, elem.getWaypoint().toArray());
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {2, 2}, elem.getNext().getWaypoint().toArray());
        assertNull(elem.getNext().getNext());
    }
```

my input is an node list like: {1,2} -> {2,3} -> {3,4} and an waypoint {5,6}.i expect my output will be: {5,6} -> {1,2} -> {2,3} -> {3,4}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addFirst(Object element)` for inseting your element at first index for example :

```
    import java.io.*; 
    import java.util.LinkedList; 

    public class LinkedListDemo { 
       public static void main(String args[]) { 

        // creating an empty LinkedList 
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(); 

        // use add() method to add elements in the list 
        list.add("Coder"); 
        list.add("ACJHP"); 
        list.add("1190"); 

        // Output the present list 
        System.out.println("The list is:" + list); 

        // Adding new elements at the beginning 
        list.addFirst("First"); 
        list.addFirst("At"); 

        // Displaying the new list 
        System.out.println("The new List is:" + list); 
    } 
}
```

So if you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) carefully you can see a lot of methods thats make your job easy

Comment: but i do not have the right to use methods like that. i have write a method by myself.

Comment: Your TourElement class should contain Array of Waypoint not single object so when you try to add it as first element your may recreate array and re order your elements as you want

Comment: Did you get what I want to say? In your `addStart()`method you just changing the next element nothing else but this is your problem you should insert new element to your list

Comment: No, my homework requires TourElement must be an object. it uses to create each element in linked list. In the test case, I have an element  elem.setWaypoint(createWaypoint(1, 2)); when I use elem = elem.addStart(createWaypoint(1, 1)); i expect that in the linklist it will be {1,1} -> {2,2}